# SQL ServerRecovery Model Change Tracking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, recovery

Are SQL Server recovery model changes logged anywhere...WMI, error logs...etc?

For instance, if I change from `FULL` to `SIMPLE`, is this recorded anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recorded in the SQL Server Error Log.

```
exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'setting database option recovery'
```

The result of that should have `Text` of:

> Setting database option RECOVERY to FULL for database 'YourDatabaseName'.